# How to break up a hex declaration into equal sized chunks?

Tags: python, hex

I have the following declaration in my code:

```
plain_text = 0x3243f6a8885a308d313198a2e03707343243f6a8885a308d313198a2e037073454a2e
```

Which I want to break up into equal sized chunks, say of 32 length each, such that I have following three parts:

```
part1 = 0x3243f6a8885a308d313198a2e0370734
part2 = 0x3243f6a8885a308d313198a2e0370734
part3 = 0x54a2e
```

Note that none of my inputs and outputs are strings. Also, in case when the total length of the plaintext is not of desired size, the last part is not discarded, but copied as it is (to some `partn`).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious thing to do is shifting and masking.

It would be easier if you wanted the lowest 16 bytes, then the next lowest, etc., with the top part incomplete, so let's do that first:

```
bits = []
while plain_text:
    bits.append(plain_text & ((1 << 128) - 1))
    plain_text >>= 128
bits.reverse()
```

Instead, it looks like you want the highest 16 bytes, etc., leaving the *smallest* part incomplete instead of the largest. But that's not a huge deal. The only tricky part is knowing what mask to start with, and you can get that with [`plain_text.bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) (or, if you're on an older version of Python, by doing the same thing manually by using the equivalent code shown in the docs). Also, it looks like you want to split on the nibble rather than the byte, but that's not too hard either:

```
bits = []
shift = (math.ceil(plain_text.bit_length() / 4) % 32) * 4
while plain_text:
    bits.append(plain_text & (1 << shift) - 1)
    plain_text >>= shift
    shift = 128
bits.reverse()
```

Does it work?

```
>>> part1, part2, part3 = bits
>>> hex(part1), hex(part2), hex(part3)
('0x3243f6a8885a308d313198a2e0370734',
 '0x3243f6a8885a308d313198a2e0370734',
 '0x54a2e')
```

As a side note, I'm a little concerned that you want to store this in variables named `part1`, `part2`, and `part3` instead of just a list called `parts` (or `bits`). What are you going to do if `plain_text` is a little bigger and won't fit into 3 parts?

Comment: It should be generalized for `n` parts; each of those n blocks being of length 32.

Comment: you could use `while n: n, r = divmod(n, 1 << 128); parts.append(r)` in the first code example.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yeah, I thought that would make the first part easier to understand, but the second part (the one he really wants) harder, so I went with shift and mask instead of div and mod. I'm not entirely sure it was the right choice, but I _think_ it was. (I could easily be clouded by doing too much assembly—including PowerPC—and C with bad optimizers and so on so I think shift-mask-rot operations are simpler than they actually are…)

Comment: @TarunVerma: If it should be generalized for `n` parts, then you _definitely_ want a single list with `n` elements, like `bits`, not `n` separate variables. If that isn't clear, see [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) and [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`textwrap.wrap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) for this:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> plain_text = 0x3243f6a8885a308d313198a2e03707343243f6a8885a308d313198a2e037073454a2e
>>> output = [int(x, 16) for x in textwrap.wrap(format(plain_text, 'x'), 32)]
>>> output
[66814286504060421741230023322616923956L, 66814286504060421741230023322616923956L, 346670]
>>> for x in output:
...     print format(x, 'x')
...     
3243f6a8885a308d313198a2e0370734
3243f6a8885a308d313198a2e0370734
54a2e
```

Comment: He doesn't have strings, he has a giant number. He doesn't want strings, he wants numbers.